# My while loop wont run

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a code here that I'm trying to run. I'm trying to write a loop that when I enter 0 it will stop prompting me from the questing I wrote. For some reason I can only enter the answers to the questions three time. Also for some reason the summary of the print out is wrong when the program returns the item number. Bellow(end) ill provide a print out. I think it has to do with my ShoppingBag class. Thanks in advance!

```
 public class ShoppingBag
 {    
    private int items;
    private float totalRetailCost;
    private float taxRate;

    public ShoppingBag(float taxRate)
    {
        this.taxRate = taxRate;
        items = 0;
        totalRetailCost = 0.0f;
    }
    public void place(int numItems, float theCost)
    {
        items += numItems;
        totalRetailCost += (numItems * theCost);
    }
    public int getItems()
    {
        return items;
    }
    public float getTotalRetailCost()
    {
        return totalRetailCost;
    }
    public float getTotalCost()
    {
        return totalRetailCost*(1+taxRate);
    }
    public String toString()
    {       
        String result = "the bag contains " + items + " items";
        result += "The retail cost of the items is = " + 
        totalRetailCost; return result += "The total cost = " + 
        getTotalCost();
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class MainClass 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner conIn = new Scanner (System.in);
        ShoppingBag sb = new ShoppingBag(0.06f);

        int count = 0;
        float cost = 0.0f;

        System.out.print("Enter count (use 0 to stop): ");

        count = conIn.nextInt();

        while (count != 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter Cost");
            cost = conIn.nextFloat();
            sb.place(count, cost);

            System.out.print("Enter count (use 0 to stop): ");
            count = conIn.nextInt();
            System.out.print(sb);

        }
        conIn.close();
    }   
}
```

### print out

Enter count (use 0 to stop): 5
Enter Cost10.5
Enter count (use 0 to stop): 2  (here it should keep running since no 0 was typed) 
the bag contains 5 itemsThe retail cost of the items is = 52.5The total cost = 55.649998Enter Cost

(it should say 7 items instead of 5 items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here, you print the bag at each iteration (check the last print).
That´s also particially the problem with the wrong item count.
The item isn´t aviable, since you didn´t place it in the bag yet.
You might want to print the `bag` object after the loop, or if you want to know what your bag does contain in the middle of the input

```
// After the loop
while (count != 0)
{
   System.out.print("Enter Cost");
   cost = conIn.nextFloat();
   sb.place(count, cost);

   System.out.print("Enter count (use 0 to stop): ");
   count = conIn.nextInt();
}
System.out.print(sb);

// After you placed the object in the bag,
// If you want the user to know what he has after each insertation
while (count != 0)
{
   System.out.print("Enter Cost");
   cost = conIn.nextFloat();
   sb.place(count, cost);

   System.out.print(sb);
   System.out.print("Enter count (use 0 to stop): ");
   count = conIn.nextInt();
}
```

EDIT: As a sidenote, your loop did run, you just thought that it was over, because you saw the bag printing. The loop itself didn´t stop, and you just had to make an input to continue there.

Comment: Thank you soo much!! Now I just have to figure out why my number are not adding up correcting when the 6% tax is included

Comment: @BioMan Even non-sentient beings know that tax is bad. This is their way of protesting.